" type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double' ", Error only appears when connect my window to my android device
I created flutter /dart project on VS code.
It runs completely fine on my windows (chrome or edge),
But when i connect it to my samsung using usb cable and run it there some of the pages works well but some of them don't show the contents of the page and just show this error in the middle of the page.

Is there a stacktrace?  If so, what is the code that is throwing the exception?

It is related to the model or entity you've made.
This is happen if your backend or API return either integer 1 or double value 1.2 .
You can handle it by using num as the data type for the expected number value.
Then you can either convert the value toString or toInt when needed.

I faced the same problem. I declared the number as double but from the backend if it is coming as int for number without floating values for example 5 then I have this problem on android and then I used toDouble() to convert it into double but when I check the return type of the number using print then it shows it is still int.  I also tried to add .00 to the number but it still returns number without floating points.
I solved it by adding  .000000000000001 to the number.
For example =
    price = json['price'] + .000000000000001;

This was maximum number of zeros for which it works. you can also use .0001  or .00001 or something else.
